# on the sufficiency of Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, optimization

Suppose that we have a nonnegative polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ and we want to minimize it subject to the polynomial constraint $h(x)=0$ with $h(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Note that $h(x)$ is a bounded constraint.

Question 1: Does this problem always have a solution?

Question 2: Suppose that the problem does have a solution. Define the Lagrangian 
$L(x)=f(x)+\lambda h(x)$. Is it always true that one of the solutions of the KKT conditions $\nabla_x L(x)=0, h(x)=0$ will be the solution of the original problem?

Question 3: What does it mean if the KKT equations do not admit any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1: As long as $h(x) = 0$ for some $x$, there will always be a solution. Hint: Use $f \ge 0$ and $f(x) \to \infty$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$.

Ad 2: You need a constraint qualification ($h(\bar x) \ne 0$ should do it for you). E.g. the minimizer $x=0$ of $f(x) = x$, $h(x) = x^3$ is not a KKT point.

Ad 3: If you know that a CQ is satisfied for all feasible $x$, it means that there is no (local) minimizer of you functional.